# How to move data between partitioned tables in Hive

Tags: hive, partitioning

I have a two tables `emp1` and `emp2` having fields-

- userid
- name
- occupation
- country

`emp1` has partition on country and `emp2` has partition on occupation

How can I move data from `emp1` to `emp2`

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite target table with a dataset from emp1 plus (`union all`) old data that was in emp2 table. Note `distribute by` at the end of the query - this is for optimizing partitions creation, final reducers will receive only their partition data, this will reduce memory consumption.

```
insert overwrite table emp2 partition(occupation) 
select userid, name, country, occupation from emp1 
union all
select userid, name, country, occupation from emp2
distribute by occupation;
```

Additionally you may add removing duplicates using row_number().

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful on their own. It would help if you could add some detail explaining how/why it answers the question.

Comment: Please edit your answer with explanation, or if you can't explain the code, please provide helpful link(s). You should avoid posting answers in fashion  that satisfy questions "gimme code please".